Lengthen tikz-cd Arrow Based on Label
I was wondering if it is possible to automatically lengthen a tikz-cd arrow based on the width of its label (perhaps with some padding)?
Typesetting, for example, the commutative diagram
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            R^2 \arrow[r,"{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}}"] \& R^2 \arrow[r] \& R
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}

results in

Changing the contents of the diagram to
R^2 \arrow[r,"{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}}"] \&[2em] R^2 \arrow[r] \& R

results in

but it would be nice to be able to automate this for consistency across different matrices.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I don't think that pmatrix is right: you see that the spacing is too big.

Thank you for your reply, I have some matrices with more complicated entries in my document for which pmatrix seems the best fit, in cases like this example I could probably use psmallmatrix from mathtools, but that still seems to protrude over the arrowhead

Do you need to use tikz-cd? What about R^2\xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}}R^2\longrightarrow R?

Thank you for your reply, I've given this as a simple example for my question but in other cases I have more complex diagrams involving vertical/diagonal arrows for which tikz-cd seems the best solution

I have a "sort of" solution for this, I say "sort of" because it is very clunky, if anyone has any better suggestions please let me know!
Using user194703's distance function from this answer, I:

Create a tikzpicture wrapped in mathclap (from mathtools) and smash, and with opacity=0, so that it is invisible and takes up no "real" space in the document.
Draw a node in this tikzpicture consisting of the matrix, using the same style as a tikz-cd label.
Measure the distance between the west and east anchors of this node, and store this as a global variable, say MatLen.
Use \&[\MatLen] after the source of the matrix in the tikzcd to achieve the desired spacing.

I have created a function to do this called CalcMatLen which takes two arguments: the first is the matrix to measure, and the second is the name of the global variable to create. I place it just before the tikzcd in the equation* environment.
The code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{distance}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xa}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@ya}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@yb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfmathparse{sqrt((\pgf@xa-\pgf@xb)*(\pgf@xa- 
\pgf@xb)+(\pgf@ya-\pgf@yb)*(\pgf@ya-\pgf@yb))}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\CalcMatLen}[2]{%
    \mathclap{%
        \smash{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram,opacity=0]
                \node (M)[commutative diagrams/.cd, every label] at (0,0) {$#1$};
                \node (A) at (M.west) {};
                \node (B) at (M.east) {};
                \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{distance("A","B")};
                \global\expandafter\let\csname #2\endcsname\temp
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    }%
}%

\def\myMatrix{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \CalcMatLen{\myMatrix}{MatLen}
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            R^2 \arrow[r,"\myMatrix"] \&[\MatLen] R^2 \arrow[r] \& R\\
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}

results in

Changing \myMatrix to
\def\myMatrix{\begin{pmatrix} aaa & bbb \\ ccc & ddd \end{pmatrix}}

then results in

I could add an argument to add/remove space either side of the matrix in the future, but this is what I have for now.

Update:
I've found that shrinking the space either side of the matrix by 1em seems a nice default (this can be changed by modifying defaultMatLenShrink), I've updated CalcMatLen to take an optional argument which increases the amount of space either side of the matrix by the amount specified:
\def\defaultMatLenShrink{1em}
\newcommand{\CalcMatLen}[3][0em]{%
    \mathclap{%
        \smash{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram,opacity=0]
                \node (M)[commutative diagrams/.cd, every label] at (0,0) {$#2$};
                \node[xshift=-#1] at ([shift={(0:\defaultMatLenShrink)}]M.west) (A) {};
                \node[xshift=#1] at ([shift={(180:\defaultMatLenShrink)}]M.east) (B) {};
                \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{distance("A","B")};
                \global\expandafter\let\csname #3\endcsname\temp
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    }%
}%

While my specific use case is matrices, this should work for other long math labels.

Update 2:
I've found while testing with very long labels that the distance function will refuse to return an answer saying Dimension too large. This could very well be a mistake on my part in how I am using it, but to get around this I have replaced it with functions from the tkz-euclide package:
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\def\defaultMatLenShrink{1em}
\newcommand{\CalcMatLen}[3][0em]{%
    \mathclap{%
        \smash{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram, opacity=0]
                \node[commutative diagrams/.cd, every label] at (0,0) (M) {$#2$};
                \node[xshift=-#1] at ([xshift=\defaultMatLenShrink]M.west) (A) {};
                \node[xshift=#1] at ([xshift=-\defaultMatLenShrink]M.east) (B) {};
                \tkzCalcLength(A,B)\tkzGetLength{dAB}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{\dAB cm}
                \global\expandafter\let\csname #3\endcsname\temp
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    }%
}%

I have also slightly simplified the code that reduces the distance by the default, and made the node definitions more consistent.
